# How can I find the cause of crash? My app doesn't appear in crashlog

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, exception

Below is a symbolicated crashlog that very few users have experience. I have never been able to reproduce the crash myself. 
Is this really my apps fault? To me it seems to be UIKit that craches without touching my classes.

Since I can't reproduce this crash, what are my options?

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib 0x3b29f626         objc_msgSend + 5
1   UIKit           0x3344c7f3         <redacted> + 1078
2   UIKit           0x334fecb3         <redacted> + 214
3   UIKit           0x333ade09         <redacted> + 316
4   UIKit           0x33326b57         <redacted> + 430
5   CoreFoundation  0x30aca039         <redacted> + 20
6   CoreFoundation  0x30ac79c7         <redacted> + 286
7   CoreFoundation  0x30ac7d13         <redacted> + 738
8   CoreFoundation  0x30a32769         CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
9   CoreFoundation  0x30a3254b         CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
10  GraphicsServices0x3599f6d3         GSEventRunModal + 138
11  UIKit           0x33391891         UIApplicationMain + 1136
12  MyApp           0x000b57c1         main (in MyApp) (main.m:17) + 26561
13  libdyld.dylib   0x3b793ab7         <redacted> + 2
```

Comment: "Is this really my apps fault?" It probably is, but without debugging it further it is impossible to know. Note that many crashing bugs are caused by something ruining the application state in some way, which doesn't crash until a few milliseconds later (or perhaps minutes later... those are bloody hard to find). The stack trace does not always tell you the line of code that caused the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really any good answer for this except to try and reproduce everything the user has done.

Try to get access to identical hardware and try simulating all network activity the user is receiving.

Whenever I've run into a crash I can't reproduce I always start adding more and more logging to a custom build of the app sent to the user who's having issues, eventually this approach should track the bug down.

Users are very good at finding problems... as an example I've had crashing bugs caused by something as silly as a user who had their timezone set to the wrong city — which meant their clock was a couple hours out compared to my server's time. The app crashed because it was processing dates in the future, which the code assumed was impossible.

So, to answer your question, start logging everything related to whatever you think might possibly be causing the crash.